# How can I swap two columns using sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to change the text in a file from this:

```
file.txt,c:\path\to\file
file.txt,c:\path with spaces\to\file
file.txt,c:\path\to\file with spaces
file.txt,c:\path\to\file with spaces
file.txt,c:\path\to\file with spaces
```

To this kind of output (one path to the file):

```
c:\path\to\file\file.txt
c:\path with spaces\to\file\file.txt
c:\path\to\file with spaces\file.txt
c:\path\to\file with spaces\file.txt
c:\path\to\file with spaces\file.txt
```

This ALMOST works but requires a ',' on the end of the line :

```
sed 's@\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)@\2,\1,\3@g' file
```

Any help would be appreciated, I don't know sed all that well...

**EDIT**

This worked for me but I would still like to add a "\" in there:

```
sed 's@\(.*\),\(.*\)@\2,\1,\3@g' file
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for your input

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Escape the backslash, `\\`.

```
sed 's/^\(.*\),\(.*\)$/\2\\\1/g' file
                       --^^--
```

Also, you only need two capturing groups.

---

But since I'm more an `awk` guy.

```
awk -F, '{ print $2 "\\" $1 }' file
```

Comment: Ah! Me too, I prefer awk but I'm actually using gnu awk in a dos batch (don't ask) and it I was afraid of spaces causing an issue...

Comment: As I understand it, the issue with using awk (or anything else) on Windows is quoting rather than spaces but if you put your awk script in a file "foo.awk" and execute it as `awk -f foo.awk file` then that avoids that issue and you don't have to fight with sed, etc. May not be worthwhile in this particular case but for anything even slightly more complicated....

Comment: @MikeQ, if I recall, DOS doesn't understand single quotes, so you might want something like `awk -F, -v OFS="\\" "{print $2, $1}" file` -- I'm not sure if the escaped backslash is required for DOS, and I don't have means to test right now.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Awk has been off the table for me for these very concerns. I wish I was back in Linux :-/ ..      I'm doing something like this now:  sed "s/^\(.*\),\(.*\)$/\2\\\1/g" temp_key_user_file_index2.txt > key_user_file_index.txt